# Why can't the Linux preemption model be changed by kernel parameter?

Tags: linux-kernel, configuration

The Linux kernel has a large set of [parameters](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt) that enable users to adjust the kernel behavior without recompiling it. There doesn't seem to be a parameter to adjust the preemption model:

```
-*- Preemption Model
            No Forced Preemption (Server) (PREEMPT_NONE)
        --> Voluntary Kernel Preemption (Desktop) (PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY)
            Preemptible Kernel (Low-Latency Desktop) (PREEMPT)
```

Why didn't the kernel developers add a switch to choose between them?

Comment: Probably because this choice changes the compilation of many parts of the kernel - it's not something that *can* easily be switched at runtime (at least without an unacceptable performance penalty that would negate the advantages of the first two).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preemption is implemented using a (large) number of explicit preemption points (look for `might_sleep` in the kernel), many of which are in somewhat hot paths. Full preemption (`CONFIG_PREEMPT`) has an even greater impact; for instance spinlocks check the preemption count (at least, on non-SMP kernels), as do IRQs.

Currently, the chosen preemption model is applied at compile-time; as a result, with no forced preemption, none of the preemption code survives in the kernel, and you get maximum throughput. Likewise, a voluntary preemption kernel doesn’t have any preemption checks in IRQ and kernel entry points. Changing this so that preemption could be changed at runtime would mean that all configurations would have to check the preemption setting, at least at boot, and suffer some cost even in the best case (*e.g.*, even if preemption was a boot-time setting, and the “no preemption” setting could patch out the relevant call sites, you’d still end up with do-nothing code taking up precious space in code caches).